# WordPress полностью выгружает css файл в html код страницы

Tags: html, css, wordpress

WordPress выгружает css файл в html страницы вместо подключения.
Т.е. вместо `<link rel="stylesheet" href=..>` в коде страницы в браузере, я вижу весь сss код целиком. Даже bootstrap.
Проверил уже кажется всё, что можно. functions.php - там всё подключено правильно. Например:

wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', '/wp-content/themes/Divi/css/bootstrap.css', array(), et_get_theme_version() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );

Сталкивался кто-нибудь? В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Может нужен не href внутри ссылки, а src?

Comment: 1. Как по-твоему "правильно" подключены стили? Покажи код, исправив вопрос. 2. Тема самописька небось?

Comment: Код написал. Тема Divi

Comment: Может там стоит какой-то плагины для "оптимизации" сайта по типу Autoptimize и там выбрана опция "Встраивать все CSS?"